# Sort attributes of items attributes in MatTableDataSource

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm showing elements in a MatTableDataSource, and I'm able to sort simple atributes like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="eventName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>EVENTO</th>
        <td *matCellDef="let item">
            {{event.name}}
        </td>
</ng-container>
```

But when I'm trying to sort atributes of atributes doesn't work, like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>NOMBRE</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
            {{item.worker.firstName}}
        </td>
</ng-container>
```

The problem is {{item.worker.firstName}}, when I'm having

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['eventName', 'firstName']
```

as my dataSource's displayedColumns

Answer (score 0):

The default `sortingDataAccessor` function of `MatTableDataSource`  can not able to reach into inner objects and access their properties(attributes).

So, to solve this you can create a custom sort function to sort the data and assign it to `dataSource.sortData` as below:

```
this.dataSource.sortData = (data, sort: MatSort) => {

      const factor =
        sort.direction == "asc" ? 1 : sort.direction == "desc" ? -1 : 0;
      if (factor) {
        data = data.sort((a, b) => {
          const afirstName = a.worker.firstName;
          const bfirstName = b.worker.firstName;
          return afirstName > bfirstName ? factor : afirstName < bfirstName ? -factor : 0;
        });
      }
      return data;
    };
```

[here is stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-rnbptv)